# Audio playback on certain link click

Tags: javascript, html

Here is an example code:

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>

<audio>
  <source src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/sounds/swoosh-enter.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Here is a fiddle with the example code that I provided:

https://jsfiddle.net/qkuLkqao/2/

All the examples that I found use mouseover, my version would be simpler than this, playing a sound file when the user clicks on a certain link.

How can I achieve this?

I did some research on SO and Google but I couldn't find anything related (most probably I didn't searched correctly).

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use js to [manipulate the audio element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_audio.asp)...

```js
let audio = document.getElementById("audio");

let link = document.getElementById("audioLink");

link.onclick = () => {
  audio.play();
};
```

```html
<a id="audioLink" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>

<audio id="audio">
  <source src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/sounds/swoosh-enter.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Take in to consideration that a link element is not mean to be a audio button.. you can use a button element instead..

Answer (score 0):

Please try that.

```
document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].addEventListener('click', player, false)

function player() {
    document.querySelector('audio').play()
}
```

This is made to play on `Link 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare use `onclick` on `a tag` and call a function to play the file.

Note. You can add the `src` path of the audio file as any data property in a tag and use it to play the related `audio` file

```js
function playThis (el) {
 
    if(window.audio) {
       audio.pause();
    }
    window.audio = new Audio (el.getAttribute("data-src"));
    window.audio.play();
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="1" data-src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/sounds/swoosh-enter.mp3" onclick="playThis(this)">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="2" data-src="http://www.evidenceaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/monsterslap.mp3" onclick="playThis(this)">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="3" data-src="http://www.evidenceaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/lyricchords.mp3" onclick="playThis(this)">Link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    audio = document.getElementById('a-on-click'),
    clickHandler = function () {
        audio.play();
    }
;

for (var i in links) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qkuLkqao/14/